# visual studio 2019 `add container orchestration support` Only shows Docker Compose

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add Kubernetes/helm support to a dot net core 3.0 project but I only see Docker Compose in the dropdown. What am I missing? I can start a new project with Kubernetes support just not able to convert a project.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4029

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same but it was solved after I installed Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes by Visual Studio installer.